# Why does module_invoke() return an empty array for anonymous users?

Tags: blocks, hooks

I'm using module_invoke to return an array of blocks in a hook_block_list_alter

```
function MY_MODULE_block_list_alter(&$blocks) {

 $foo = &drupal_static('foo');
 foreach ($blocks as $key => $block) {
  if ($block->module == 'bean') {
   $bar = module_invoke($block->module, 'block_view ', $block->delta);
   $foo[] = $bar;
  }
 }
 return $foo;
}
```

When I'm logged in with admin privileges, $bar will be an array containing $bar['content'], $bar['subject'] etc. But for anonymous users, the array is empty. I can't find any reason for this, hopefully I'm missing something obvious and easy (to others!).

Comment: The second argument is `'block_view '` with a space at the end. I guess that is a typo made writing the code here, or the code would return an empty array even for the user #1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are invoking the function bean_block_view(), which contains this code:

```
if (bean_access('view', $bean) && $bean) {
  $content = $bean->view($bean->view_mode);
  if (!is_array($content)) {
    $content = array(
      '#markup' => $content,
    );
  }

  $return = array(
    'content' => $content, 
    'subject' => isset($bean->title) ? $bean->title : '',
  );
}
```

Looking at the first line of code, you can see the block is only built if the viewer has 'view' access for beans.

So it's a permissions issue of some sort with the beans module. Anonymous users don't have the required permission, so the block is empty.

Comment: Thanks @Jaypan, I think I just needed to write this out and get another set of eyes, this is definitely a bean permissions issue.